# Customize mailer-daemon error messages in LAMP

Tags: email, lamp, daemon

I need to customize bounce and error messages sent from MAILER-DAEMON in a LAMP environment.  Instead of the standard message

> From: Mailer-Daemon@xxxxxx.co.uk
>
> To: johndoe@hotmail.com
>
> Subject: Mail delivery failed: returning message to sender
> Date: Tue, 16 Sep 2014 16:42:14 -0300
>
> This message was created automatically by mail delivery software.
>
> A message that you sent could not be delivered to one or more of its
> recipients. This is a permanent error. The following address(es) failed:
>
> olliecromwell@befree.co.uk
>
> mailbox is full: retry timeout exceeded

i need the mailer-daemon to send a custom message of my client's choosing.

any suggestions?

Comment: It would be extremely helpful if you could add which MTA (mail server) you are using.

Comment: @mtak TKS! i will check precisely and get back to you, as well as edit it into the question.